# How do I configure the workspace in OMS for Automation and Control

Tags: azure, oms

I am using a trial license to monitor my home PC as part of a simple demo/test environment to allow me to play with the features.

When I try to add Automation and Control I am asked to Configure Workspace.  This them prompts me to configure an Automation Account.  I have no existing accounts available to use and get the following message when trying to create one

Cannot link Automation account with workspace.

I would like to enable the following solutions (Update Management and Change Tracking)but both require this configuration.

Any assistance with this would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate the same Resource group with the OMS in Azure portal, create the workspace and the Automation account there.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an Azure PowerShell Automation account through the Azure portal that you then link to OMS. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/learning-paths/automation/) for details on Azure Automation.

Comment: That doesn't seem to link to anything that would show the user how to link an automation account to OMS.

Comment: @milbauer correct, because that is not what the question is asking. They are already at the point in the OMS process where it is asking to link an automation account, but they don't have an automation account. The answer to the question is "create an automation account"